# Reproducing a graphic on Jensen's inequality for the probabilistic case

Tags: graphics, probability-or-statistics

I am trying to reproduce the following graph on Jensen's inequality for the probabilistic case (source: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Jensen_graph.png)) but with

- the exponential function as Y,
- the normal distribution on the X-axis and therefore
- the log-normal distribution on the Y-axis coming out or the transformation.

[image]

I am not really a well versed user of Mathematica and here I don't have any idea whatsoever how to achieve the task. Thank you for your help.

**EDIT**: To be more specific: I know how to plot the original distribution. What I don't know is how to turn the resulting distribution around by 90° in the same diagram.

Comment: Have you already tried anything or browsed the online help or this site for related questions? Showing at least some effort on your behalf will better your chances of getting help.

Comment: There's a `Plot` command. Have a look at the online help for it, and see how you get on.

Comment: @YvesKlett: Yes, I have. I guess my problem was the turning the resulting distribution around by 90°.

Comment: @cormullion: I know that there is a plot command ;-) My problem was how to turn the resulting distribution around by 90°

Comment: @Downvoters: Thank you for your hints how to improve my question. I hope that the clarification now helps.

Comment: @vonjd No worries - my mind-reading skills not working well today... :)

Comment: @cormullion: Thank you, I hope that some of the downvoters would reconsider after my clarification... sigh

Comment: Imagine *me* sighing when first taking a look at your question. Reconsidered.

Comment: You'll certainly avoid downvotes in this kind of questions simply by posting your (perhaps non-working but self-contained) minimal code sample.

Comment: @belisarius Point taken - thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another version of the same kind of figure, with some knobs to move things around:

```
DynamicModule[{fun, gauss},
 gauss[\[Mu]_, \[Sigma]_, x_] := 
  PDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], x];
 fun[x_] := x^4/4^4*4;
 Manipulate[
  Show[
   Plot[
    {fun[x], gauss[\[Lambda], \[Sigma], x]},
    {x, 0, 4},
    PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
    PlotStyle -> Thick,
    Epilog -> {{Dashed, Thick, Lighter@Orange, 
       InfiniteLine@{{#, 0}, {#, 1}} &@\[Lambda]},
      {Dashed, Thick, Lighter@Red, 
       InfiniteLine@{{0, #}, {1, #}} &@fun[\[Lambda]]},
      {Dashed, Thick, Lighter@Purple, 
       InfiniteLine@{{0, #}, {1, #}} &@
        NIntegrate[
         gauss[\[Lambda], \[Sigma], x] fun[x], {x, 0, 10}]}}
    ],
   ParametricPlot[{gauss[\[Lambda], \[Sigma], y], fun@y}, {y, 0, 10}, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
   ],
  {{\[Lambda], 2.5}, 0.001, 4, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{\[Sigma], 0.5}, 0.01, 2, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  ControlPlacement -> Right
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Very impressive!

Answer (score 18):

To make this plot, you first need to know about `PDF`, which gives the probability distribution functions for various distributions. Your distributions are `NormalDistribution` and `LogNormalDistribution`, which isn't too hard to figure out. To make the normal plot, you can just use `Plot`. Since the log-normal is vertical, you need something else; `ParametricPlot` works well. The exponential is pretty trivial.

The styling of each line is done using `PlotStyle`. The L-shaped lines can be added as an `Epilog` to a Plot, but since I'm combining several plots already, I just made a separate Graphics object for them. I also add the stray Text at the same time.

We remove the numeric ticks by setting `Ticks` to a custom set, which we use to mark the E(X) and Y(E(X). The axes labels are just `AxesLabel` and we get pretty arrows by adding `Arrowheads` to `AxesStyle`.

```
Module[{xlist = {3/4, 1/3, 1/2, 5/4}}, 
 Show[Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[1, 0.2]][x], {x, 0, 2}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Gray]], Plot[Exp[x], {x, 0, 2}], 
  ParametricPlot[{PDF[LogNormalDistribution[1, 0.2]][y], y}, {y, 0, 
    5}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Gray]], 
  Graphics[{Transpose[{{Red, Black, Black, Black}, 
      Line[{{#, 0}, {#, Exp[#]}, {0, Exp[#]}}] & /@ xlist}], {Blue, 
     Text[Y == \[CurlyPhi][X], {3/2, Exp[3/2]}, {1.1, 0}]}}], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 5}}, 
  Ticks -> {{{First[xlist], \[DoubleStruckCapitalE][X]}}, {{Exp[
       First[xlist]], Y[\[DoubleStruckCapitalE][X]]}}}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, AxesLabel -> {X, Y}, 
  AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.05}]]]
```

[image: final graphic]

Comment: Wow - Thank you: +1!